# Trying to understand why this code doesn't return the same values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Python and pandas, I'm trying to get an understanding of the difference between two sets of codes and why they do different things.

I've tried separating the lines of code but the code still gives off different answers

What proportion of female students are majoring in physics?

Code1:

```
fem_phy = df.query("gender == 'female' & major == 'Physics'").count() / 
         (df.query("gender=='female'")).count()
fem_phy
```

Code2:

```
len(df[(df['gender'] == 'female') & (df['admitted']) & 
   (df['major']=='Physics')]) / len(df[(df['gender']=='female') & 
   (df['admitted'])])
```

I expect the second set of code to return `0.120623` like the first

Comment: I would guess this has nothing to do with Python. It looks like you are making the assumption that every woman who *applied* to do a major was *admitted*. Some people will have been rejected. There is likely a different physics/other-major ratio between women who were rejected and those who were accepted, which would explain the different numbers.

Comment: You are right, thanks Dunes

Answer (score 0):

Check:

```
#sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'gender':['female'] * 3 + ['male'] * 2,
                   'major':['Physics'] * 2 + ['Math'] * 3})

print (df)
   gender    major
0  female  Physics
1  female  Physics
2  female     Math
3    male     Math
4    male     Math
```

For filtering of rows is correct use [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) or [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), for second is removed `df['admitted']` for same output:

```
print (df.query("gender == 'female' & major == 'Physics'"))
   gender    major
0  female  Physics
1  female  Physics

print (df.query("gender=='female'"))
   gender    major
0  female  Physics
1  female  Physics
2  female     Math

print (df[(df['gender']=='female') & (df['major']=='Physics')])
   gender    major
0  female  Physics
1  female  Physics

print (df[(df['gender']=='female')])
   gender    major
0  female  Physics
1  female  Physics
2  female     Math
```

Problem is with [`DataFrame.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) - it return number of rows excluded misisng values - so here get `Series` with all `2` values (because no missing values in data):

```
print (df.query("gender == 'female' & major == 'Physics'").count())
gender    2
major     2
dtype: int64
```

Correct using is get length with `len`:

```
print (len(df.query("gender == 'female' & major == 'Physics'")))
2

print (len(df[(df['gender']=='female') & (df['major']=='Physics')]))
2
```

Or count only `True` values of mask by `sum`:

```
print ((df['gender']=='female') & (df['major']=='Physics'))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool

print (((df['gender']=='female') & (df['major']=='Physics')).sum())
2
```

So all together is:

```
mask1 = (df['gender']=='female')
mask2 = (df['major']=='Physics')
print ((mask1 & mask2).sum() / mask1.sum())
0.6666666666666666

df1 = df.query("gender == 'female' & major == 'Physics'")
df2 = df.query("gender=='female'")
print (len(df1) / len(df2))
0.6666666666666666

df1 = df[(df['gender']=='female') & (df['major']=='Physics')]
df2 = df[(df['gender']=='female')]
print (len(df1) / len(df2))
0.6666666666666666
```